# How to add commas to number every 3 digits in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

If I have a number `int aNum = 2000000` how do I format this so that I can display it as the NSString 2,000,000?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Don't do your own number formatting. You will almost certainly not get all the edge cases right or correctly handle all possible locales. Use the [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for formatting numeric data to a localized string representation.

You would use the `NSNumberFormatter` instance method `-setGroupingSeparator:` to set the grouping separator to `@","` (or better yet `[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator]`; thanks @ntesler) and `-setGroupingSize:` to put a grouping separator every 3 digits.

Comment: Cool, am I all set after I -setGroupingSize: ? Or do I need to -setFormat: ?

Comment: Better off localizing it with `[formatter setGroupingSeparator: [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator]];`

Comment: NSNumberformatter is not good enough, especially if you need to be prepared for international formats.

Comment: NSNumberFormatter doesn't handle NSDecimalNumber well enough. It loses precision.

Comment: What could be proper solution if i want dot(.) instead of comma(,) ?

Answer (score 149):

Use `NSNumberFormatter`.

Specifically:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // this line is important!

NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2000000]];

[formatter release];
```

By default `NSNumberFormatter` uses the current locale so the grouping separators are set to their correct values by default. The key thing is to remember to set a number style.

Comment: yes I had similar problem it wouldnt parse "200,000", even if I had set the locale to English UK, until I had set the style to NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle. Think it would only understand the string "200000"

Comment: @MCKapur why do you say new is old school? It does not make sense typing more to do the same, isn't it?

Comment: @JulioBailon WOW this was like 2 years ago. Honestly don't remember why I said +new was old school. It isn't. I do however prefer +alloc-init for consistency, +new always felt like an unnecessary shortcut, and +alloc-init helped me keep good code practice.

Comment: What if I want both commas and the decimal places?

Answer (score 34):

There's a [static method on `NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumberFormatter/localizedStringFromNumber:numberStyle:) that does just what you need:

```
int aNum = 2000000;
NSString *display = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:@(aNum)
                                                     numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
```

This way is a little more succinct than creating a new `NSNumberFormatter` if you don't need to do any additional configuration of the formatter.

Answer (score 18):

Even easier:

```
NSNumber *someNumber = @(1234567890);
NSString *modelNumberString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@", someNumber];
NSLog(@"Number with commas: %@", modelNumberString);
```

coworker just taught me this today. #amazing

Comment: localizedStringWithFormat depends on your current locale and for different languages produces different separators.

Answer (score 16):

Think some as i will get this post looking for sample.
So if you are working with number make attention on next params:

```
setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle // if you are working with currency
```

It could be also

```
setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle
```

All code is For ARC.

If you are working with Integer and need to get result such as 200,000

```
int value = 200000;
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString * newString =  [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]];
```

If you are working with Float and need to get result such as 200,000.00

```
float value = 200000;
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2]; // Set this if you need 2 digits
NSString * newString =  [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:value]];
```

**EDIT**

To have ability to use different digital separators use `NSLocale`.
Add to code where `NSLocale` is specified on Locale Identifier:

```
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"]];
```

or use current local:

```
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Comment: If i want dot(.) instead of comma(,) then ?

Comment: simple way us to use `NSLocale` just add `[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"]];` to use different separator, depends on local digital style

Comment: How to display 5,234.00... i need to display 2 decimal numbers

Comment: @Singapore use `setMaximumFractionDigits` to set up number digits you need

Answer (score 1):

Swift version

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = decimalPlaces
let result = formatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: 8.0))
```

By http://ios.eezytutorials.com

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution could be this. My answer is almost same like @Nazir's answer but with a small trick.

```
double current_balance = 2000000.00;

NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
//[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];  //if you want for currency with $ sign
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2]; // Set this if you need 2 digits
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2]; // Set this if you need 2 digits
NSString * currency_format =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:current_balance]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 4.0**

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()

formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

let result = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 123456))
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to do it with strings of numbers and not just integers (I.e. Big Numbers) I made the following macro:

```
#define addCommas(__string) (\
(^NSString *(void){\
NSString *__numberString = __string;\
NSString *__integerPortion = __numberString;\
NSString *__decimalPortion = @"";\
if ([__string containsString:@"."]) {\
__integerPortion = [__numberString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][0];\
__decimalPortion = st(@".%@", [__numberString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][1]);\
}\
int __i = (int)__integerPortion.length-3;\
while (__i > 0) {\
__integerPortion = st(@"%@,%@", substringInRange(__integerPortion, 0, __i), substringInRange(__integerPortion, __i, (int)__integerPortion.length));\
__i -= 3;\
}\
__numberString = st(@"%@%@", __integerPortion, __decimalPortion);\
return __numberString;\
})()\
)
```