# how to format the number with commas in iPhone programing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to format the number separated by comma for every 3 digits.
    For ex:12346778, I want this number as 12,346,778
    Can anyone please Suggest sample code for this.
    Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add commas to number every 3 digits in Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233824/how-to-add-commas-to-number-every-3-digits-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 8):

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];  
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Use the method

```
- (void)setGroupingSeparator:(NSString *)string
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSInteger currency = 123456789;
NSNumberFormatter *num = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[num setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *numberAsString = [num stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currency]];
[num release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you. Very easy for understand!

```
NSNumberFormatter *mVolFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[mVolFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"#,##0"];
[mVolFormatter setZeroSymbol:@"-"];
long Vol = 5000000;
NSString *strYouNeed = [mVolFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:vol]];
```

and =>> strYouNeed = @"5,000,000"

Check my code!!!