# Grouping separator while changing value in UITextfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsnumber

In order to edit a group-separated number in an `UITextField` the grouping separator needs to get switched of while editing. Otherwise the returned value (stored as `NSNumber` value) is (NULL) due to missplaced gouping separators (see the picture and imagine the number is going to be extended by another digit e.g. to "50.0000").

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Right now the value is handled in `-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method.

(My locale is German so the "." is the grouping separator not the decimal separator!) But I try to get the code working for all regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this solution :

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

 NSString *stringWithoutDots = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""]; //remove dots

int number = [stringWithoutDots intValue]; //convert into int

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // this line is important!

NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:number]];



}
```

I hope this help you.
Kevin MACHADO

Comment: Thanks thedjnivek, I'll check that out. Give me some time.

Comment: I had to adapt it slightly but you gave me some good hints. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to *thedjnivek* and his second suggestion. I had to adapt it a little bit and now it work like a charm. Just for all with the same issue here my final code:

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

NSMutableString* mstring = [[textField text] mutableCopy];

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSString* localeSeparator = [[NSLocale currentLocale]
                             objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];
NSNumber* number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:[mstring
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:localeSeparator withString:@""]];

    [textField setText:[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number]];        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see here the answer :

[How to add commas to number every 3 digits in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233824/how-to-add-commas-to-number-every-3-digits-in-objective-c)

> Don't do your own number formatting. You will almost certainly not get
>   all the edge cases right or correctly handle all possible locales. Use
>   the NSNumberFormatter for formatting numeric data to a localized
>   string representation.
>
> You would use the NSNumberFormatter instance method
>   -setGroupingSeparator: to set the grouping separator to @"." (or better yet [[NSLocale currentLocale]
>   objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator]; thanks @ntesler) and
>   -setGroupingSize: to put a grouping separator every 3 digits.

++,
Kevin MACHADO

Comment: Thanks thedjnivek, I use the `NSNumberFormatter` in order to create the separated output in the text field. The problem occurs when a edited (extended) number in the text field is returned to a (formatted) NSNumber object. If the number is extended by e.g. one digit the returned value is (NULL) due to the missplaces grouping separator. For example: the text field shows "50.000", the user adds a digit at the end to "50.0000", when now returned the text is not returnable as a group separated number object anymore.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, I did not understand :)